# Why was this question about public transportation etiquette closed as "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm referring to this question: [Not sure if have to give up priority seat as not sure if lady is pregnant or just plus sized](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9195/not-sure-if-have-to-give-up-priority-seat-as-not-sure-if-lady-is-pregnant-or-jus)

The basic question there is:

> When I can't tell if a lady is pregnant or not, should I offer my seat to her? If so, how?

This was put on hold as **primarily opinion-based**.

Now, we have another very similar question (possible duplicate?) here: [When to Offer Your Seat](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/309/when-to-offer-your-seat), which seems to me a broader version of this question. It is well-received (+16/-0) and was never placed on-hold.

I don't see why this is "primarily opinion-based" and the other is not. Anyone want to weigh in?

Comment: if anything, shouldn't it be closed as duplicate?

Comment: @Stacey Yes, perhaps! That would make more sense to me than "opinion-based".

Comment: That other question was one of the first questions asked on IPS.SE (it's from June 29, first question ever: June 27).

Comment: The question lacks many details, e. g. a culture tag, who are the priority seats for etc.? *"Therefore how should I handle this situation? Would It be ok to ask her politely if she needs the seat or should I just stand or should I just remain seated?"* We can't tell the OP what she *should* do. And we can't read that other woman's mind, so do we know if it would be ok for her.

Comment: @AnneDaunted You know, I did see the timestamp, but I forgot how young this site was >_>

Comment: @AnneDaunted Missing details = "too broad" or "unclear". Why didn't anyone comment this to the OP? Isn't "how should I handle this" asking for proper etiquette, which is on-topic?

Comment: See: [Is “what should I do” question on topic here?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1310/31)

Comment: @ArwenUndómiel OP tagged this "politeness" and "courtesy". She is asking "what is the polite thing to do", which *is* on topic.

Comment: *"She is asking "what is the polite thing to do""* No, she is not. One of her questions is, whether she should ask her *politely* or not ask at all.

Comment: @AnneDaunted She asks "*would it be ok* (polite, courteous) to ask her politely". To me, that sounds like she's asking about *common courtesy* on public transit, and such etiquette (given a culture/location) is fairly standard. However your comments have answered my question of why others saw it different, so thank you for that! Do you believe the other question should also be closed, or how is it different?

Comment: This may be worth its own meta post, instead of discussing it here. But the older question appears to be more on topic than the newer one, since it has a culture tag. Also *"If so, how can this be done without coming across as patronising?"* is on topic. *"Is it still appropriate to make the assumption that such individuals should be offered a seat?"* is maybe debatable, but this is really asking about contemporary etiquette, not a "Should I...?" question.