# "What to do" rebranded to "How to do"

Tags: discussion, scope

Since we've determined that ["What should I do?" questions are off-topic](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/are-what-should-i-do-questions-on-topic-here), it seems like instead of trying to focus on a specific interpersonal skill, people just reword their question so that it is *technically* fitting. For instance, renaming questions like "What do I tell X when Y happens?" get renamed to "How do I tell X about Z when Y happens?". I personally see no distinction between the two, and it just seems like a quick way to get someone to tell you what to do, while disguising it as a "how to do".

While questions like "How do I communicate X in a Y environment" or "How do I approach X about Y tactfully" can be on-topic, often times the level of specificity suggests that some people just want some "ideas" for them to get about a problem, instead of focusing on an interpersonal skill or a problem that might help other users.

What is our stance on it? Is it alright to just replace "What" with "How" in a question that was originally opinion-based?

<sub>I didn't link any specific example because I felt there was no need for name-calling or something similar, but if needed I can provide some</sub>

Comment: I don't mean to seem hostile by VTC on meta :) but I think that's discussing the same issue you're bringing up here?

Comment: Fair enough. I couldn't find it because the wording there was "Should I" instead of "What do I". My bad for not being more thorough with my search before posting