# Why do I get “on hold”?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I’m asking this question because, in [**this question**](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/19490/13918) which I posted, I have corrected myself. And of course, I have bulled only her, but not in front of her.

**Question:** Why do I get “on hold messages”? For example:

- [**How can I ask my classmates to do as I want?**](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/18923/13918).

What’s wrong in this? I have seen many users who ask similar like this one, but they don’t get “on hold”. For example, in [**here**](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/19512/13918). To me is seems unfair, that I get on hold, but others don’t.

What’s wrong with this?

Comment: spiral succulent's answer covers the issue well, but one more observation: holds don't last forever. A lot of questions are put on hold (for various reasons), edited to fix the issue that caused the hold, and then the hold is removed. Just because a question is not on hold now doesn't mean that it never was, and questions on hold for too long get closed.

Answer (score 6):

"Asking "What should I do?" is off topic. - Questions should ask for help achieving a specific goal. Your question is asking for personal advice on "what to do" without defining a goal; this is too subjective. Edit your question to explain what you hope to achieve and how you would like to interact with the others involved."

Why "What should I do?" is off topic is covered here [Are "what should I do" questions on topic here?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1310/11811)

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Might also be worth putting this meta in there somewhere that specifically discusses *why* "What should I do?" is off-topic: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1310/11811

Comment: Ok, then can you ask on here to grant us permission to ask “what should I do”?

Comment: @AlexA sorry, not gonna happen. There's a reason why these questions are off-topic (see all the links provided here)